# Definition conflicts with a previous value after moving table functions into another function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, sockets

Because of the scope limit I have with socket.on("reply"), so I have to move all of my table functions inside the function addHandler()

as you can see, func addHandler() does inherit from SecondViewController and two errors occur after I move my table functions

1) Type SecondViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

2) Definition conflicts with previous value (this is the part I don't understand)

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{//error 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Second view loaded")
    self.title = "Ranking"

    addHandler()
    socket.connect()

}

func addHandler()->SecondViewController{
    socket.on("reply") {data, ack in
        let json = JSON(data)
        print(json[0].count)
        let pCount:Int = json[0].count

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            //return data.count when data is available from server
            return pCount
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {//error 2
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            //everything refers to this
            let patient = patientSample[indexPath.row] as Patient

            if let cellList = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel{
                cellList.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
            }

            //setting up cell connection
            if let sexIcon = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UIImageView{
                sexIcon.image = self.genderIcon(patient.isMale!)
            }

            if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as? UILabel{
                nameLabel.text = patient.name
            }

            if let scoreLabel = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UILabel{
                scoreLabel.text = String(patient.score)
            }
            return cell
        }

        for var i=0; i<pCount; ++i{
            let patient = Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)
        }
    }//end of function addHandler
}



//gender icon
func genderIcon(isMale:Bool) -> UIImage{
    if isMale == true{
        return UIImage(named: "boy")!
    }else{
        return UIImage(named: "girl")!
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Error #1:** 
Is due to the fact that your class `SecondViewController` isn't implementing the required methods needed when adopting the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate. This is because the scope of your tableView methods are unreachable.

**Error #2:**
In swift you can't declare functions within functions like you have done.

Take all of your TableView related methods out of the `addHandler()` method.

If you want the tableView to reload the data when the socket receives a 'reply' message. Use `tableview.reloadData()`.